# Xcode typedef of struct creating error / warning

Tags: c++, c, xcode, struct, typedef

Just wondering if I am making some stupid mistake or its Xcode.

I have typedef of a struct and now while comparing the pointer between two variable of same type, creates a incompatible pointer in Xcode but not in linux. Could any one please let me know whats going on here.

```
typedef struct Node
{
    // treeNode has a hidden Address
    int size;
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;

} treeNode;

treeNode* FindMin(treeNode *node)
{
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        return node;
    }
    if(node->left) 
        return FindMin(node->left); // Error :- treeNode is incompatible with Node
    else
        return node;
}


// If I type cast it .. Show no sign of error..


treeNode* FindMin(treeNode *node)
{
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        /* There is no element in the tree */
        return node;
    }
    if(node->left) 
        return FindMin((struct Node *)node->left); // No Error here
    else
        return node;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a warning from Xcode? Or is it a compiler error? If so, what error did you get and what are your compiler flags?

Answer (score 1):

Make your declaration of treenode like this

```
typedef struct treeNode
{...
```

instead of

```
typedef struct Node
{...
```

You are accessing `struct treeNode` in the declaration `struct treeNode *left;` below, but are declaring the struct as `struct Node`